# How to update a prior probability distribution of hurricane occurrence based on absence of hurricanes to date?

Tags: time-series, likelihood, prior, posterior

For a forecasting tournament, I am trying to forecast the number of Atlantic basin hurricanes in the 2022 hurricane season. I have reason to believe that my prior distribution looks as follows:

[image: prior distribution]

At the time of writing this, we're a little over two months into the (six month) season and so, far, no hurricanes have developed. I think the absence of hurricanes so far is good reason to update my prior distribution.

I don't, however, know how to do this.

What I did do: I've explored the long-term record of hurricane occurrence. Going by that record, of all hurricanes that occurred in the 1851 through 2021 hurricane seasons, approx. 20% would have occurred by August 5:

[image: empirical distribution of data of cyclogenesis]

This is how far I got.

My question is: how can I update my prior based on the number of occurrences to date?

While we're currently looking at an absence of any hurricanes to date, the solution would be required to also be able to adjust the distribution if, for example, a first hurricane will have developed by August 10 and a second by August 15. How to adjust/update then?

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Isn't it something seasonal, so rather than a few months of data, it should be rather a few years? If you are going to predict snowfall in Europe, a few months of weather data from the summer might not be sufficient...

Comment: Both the prior distribution and the empirical distribution of the date of cyclogenesis are based on approx. 170 years of data. The analogy with snowpacks would be, how would my prediction change if, two months into winter, we hadn't seen any snow yet?

Comment: A relevant question, which you can explore given the historical data, may be whether the event "hurricane occurs in first half of hurricane season" changes the probability of the event "hurricane occurs in the second half of hurricane season".